# "read: -a: unknown option" when running script with ksh

Tags: ksh

Hello i was able to run one of the script from putty terminal without any issue as follows

```
sh  file_validation_generic.sh 1 /test/data/infa_shared/dev/scripts
```

but when i try to execute the script from a tool it is giving below error

```
 sh -c "ksh /test/data/infa_shared/dev/scripts/file_validation_generic.sh 1 /test/data/infa_shared/dev/scripts"

error :-

/test/data/infa_shared/dev/scripts/file_validation_generic.sh[121]: read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsSv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n count] [-N count]
            [var?prompt] [var ...]
```

this error occurs in a while loop during the read to an array

```
 IFS="~"
                read -a star <<< "$line"
                col_pos=${star[1]}
                col_patt=${star[6]}
```

Comment: seems like `read` is implemented differently in the `ksh` shell than in `sh`.

Comment: Thanks it worked i did SET -A